# Select related entities in entity getter method in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, repository, entity

how I can create the custom finder in Symfony2, what I can call from object context(like getter method) instead of repository context. Here is my query in EntityRepository class:

```
public function getUpVotes($trip_id)
{
    return count($this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('t')
        ->from('VputiTripBundle:Trip', 't')
        ->join('t.ratings', 'r')
        ->where('r.trip = :tid')
        ->andWhere('r.up = :up')
        ->setParameters(['tid' => $trip_id, 'up' => 1])
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult());
}
```

The goal of do that, is that I will be able to call this $model->getUpVotes() instead of call entity repository and pass parameters manualy.

Comment: Entities do not have access to the entity manager.  Injecting the manager is frowned upon and not really pretty.  Give Doctrine 2 a chance and do things the "right way" by either loading your up votes in the original query or by creating a up vote service.  If all this still feels awkward then switch to an active record implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the association set then you can use a get with a filter.

```
public function getUpVotes()
{
    return $this->ratings->filter(
        function (RatingInterface $rating) {
            return 1 === $rating->getUp();
        }
    );
}
```